# I can't convert json string to List<T> by GSON

Tags: java, gson

I want convert Json string to List by GSON library.

```
 public <T> List<T> getModelList(String jsonStr, Class<T> type) {
        Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<T>>(){}.getType();
        List<T> yourClassList = new Gson().fromJson(jsonStr, listType);
        return yourClassList;
    }
```

and I call

```
List<CallDetail> callDetails = Converter.me().getModelList(responseMessage.getResult(), CallDetail.class);
```

But I get List with `com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap` object but I need `List<CallDetail>`

Json string fragment

```
"result": "[{\"servedimei\":\"3579330679481801\",\"тип сетевого события\":\"Исходящий голос\",\"время начала события\":\"2016-01-01 19:33:10.0\"
```

POJO

```
public class CallDetail {

    private String servedimei;
    @SerializedName("тип сетевого события")
    private String type;
    @SerializedName("время начала события")
    private String starttime;
    @SerializedName("вызывающий абонент")
    private String src;
    @SerializedName("вызываемый абонент")
    private String dest;
    @SerializedName("длительность")
    private String duration;
    @SerializedName("базовая станция")
    private String bs;
    private String lac;
    private String ci;
```

Comment: can you please send any sample json string?

Comment: json string is normal but now I add it and my pojo

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple from logs. JSON string contains `result` field that contains `array` and GSON treat it as `Map`. You need one more class to get the desired result.

```
class CallDetailResult {
        List<CallDetail> result;
        // getter and setter
}

// how to use GSON here to get the desired result
CallDetailResult  result = new Gson().fromJson(jsonStr, CallDetailResult.class);
List<CallDetail> list = result.getResult();
```

Read more at [www.json.org](http://www.json.org/)

[image]

[image]

Comment: your JSON string doesn't start with `[...]` that represents array. you have to pass just the string of `result` field.